# JQuery change all elements text

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I need jquery to change numbers in all of pages. for example i want change 1 to ۱ so i tried this way:

```
$("*").each(function(){
    $(this).html(  $(this).html().replace(1,"۱")  );
})
```

but this will change css rules and attributes also. is there any trick to escape css and attributes?

Comment: Why `each`? This should do it: `$('*').text(function(i, text) { return text.replace(1,"۱");});`

Comment: @Felix `text()` rewriting destroys child elements: http://jsfiddle.net/GaHvH/

Comment: @SimeVidas: Right.... it was late yesterday ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a job that jQuery naturally fits into. Instead of getting jQuery to fetch a flat list of all elements, recursively traverse through the DOM tree yourself, searching for **text nodes** to perform the replace on.

```
function recursiveReplace(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("1", "۱");
    } else if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        $(node).contents().each(function () {
            recursiveReplace(this);
        });
    }
}

recursiveReplace(document.body);
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xKFaU/).

Comment: @Šime thanks. Just habit to include an `if-return` block in recursive functions.

Comment: To bad that ES5's `forEach` doesn't work on NodeLists. Otherwise, we could do `node.childNodes.forEach(...)` and remove jQuery from the equation completely.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("body *").each(function() { 
    if ( this.childElementCount > 0 ) { return; }
    $(this).text(function(i, v) { return v.replace('1','۱'); }); 
});
```

**Update:** doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing an actual example of your code it is hard to provide a good answer, but I will do my best.

Here is what I would do. I would wrap all of your page numbers in a  tag with a particular ID, like this...

```
<span class="pageNumber">1</span>
...
<span class="pageNumber">n</span>
```

Then here is the jQuery...

```
$.each($("span.pageNumber"), function()) {
    $(this).text('value');
});
```

You could increment the values in the loop to count for pages, or anything else you want!

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: Definitely the best method, if you control the HTML generation (just use class instead of id on those spans).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use classes, instead of IDs?