# Jquery $(element).contents().first().text("new text") doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find anything about this on Google or here.

I have a div with in it, some text and some html as such:

```
<div id="test-div">
    http://<strong>somewebsite.com</strong>/big/long/unfriendly/path/
</div>
```

What I want to do, is add a `<wbr>` after every slash. (Because the value doesn't wrap otherwise and messes up my table). Doing a simple replace on the `$('#test-div').html()` will also mess with the strong tag, so that's not an option.

I figured using `$('#test-div').contents()` to filter out the text parts (recursively) would work. However I can't seem to edit the individual bits returned. I would expect this to change the http:// part:

```
$('#test-div').contents().first().text("something");
```

However it does nothing. I know I have my navigation right, because something like this:

```
$('#test-div').contents().first().wrap( "<b></b>" );
```

does work.

Why can't I change the text bit?
(A more elegant solution to the initial problem would also be great)

Comment: `.text` probably only works on element nodes. This works fine: `$('#test-div').contents().first()[0].nodeValue = "something";` http://jsfiddle.net/2Gz8p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found my own answer thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494259/jquery-change-all-elements-text) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698673/add-html-to-text-node-extracted-via-node-nodevalue) item. I now have a function that replaces all text in all text nodes in context. It can also insert HTML into said nodes.

JavaScript function:

```
function recursiveReplace(node, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // text node
        $(node).replaceWith(node.nodeValue.replace(oldValue, newValue));
    } else if (node.nodeType === 1) { // element
        $(node).contents().each(function() {
            recursiveReplace(this, oldValue, newValue);
        });
    }
}

//To call
div = $('#test-div');
recursiveReplace(div[0], "/", "/<wbr />");
```

This solved it in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$('#test-div').contents().filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'http://';
}).remove().end().prepend('something');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLrZR/)

or,

```
$('#test-div').contents().first().remove().end().prepend("something");
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLrZR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$(element).html('your content here');
```

Comment: I have, however my initial problem is that I need to replace slashes in the text bits, while leaving any html tags intact.

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex to replace the `/`'s with `/<wbr>`?

```
$('#test-div').html($('#test-div').html().replace(/(<)?[/]/g, function($0,$1){ 
    return $1?$0:'/<wbr>';
}));
```

`/(<)?[/]/g` will look for all forward slashes, but also take special note of any closing tags.

`return $1?$0:'/<wbr>';` will ignore `</`, but replace any other `/` with `/<wbr>`

You may want to consider closing the `wbr` tag off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$('#test-div').html().replace('/', '/<wbr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

because when you say first it give you `[object Text]` and text property not work with it, easiest solution is:

```
$("#test-div").contents()[0].textContent="Something";
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq6Gx/1/)