# Convert/Replace all text in an html page with HTML entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

I need to automatically edit some html files kept in a database. I'm doing a script using node.js to get the files, then I use jsdom and jquery to do the editions I need.

Finally I need to save the files back to the database, however, all text should use HTML entities.

So, for instance, this page:

```
<html>
 <header>
  <title>Título da página</title>
 </heade>
 <body>
  <h1> Aqui também há acentos </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Should be saved as:

```
<html>
 <header>
  <title>T&#xED;tulo da p&#xE1;gina</title>
 </heade>
 <body>
  <h1> Aqui tamb&#xE9;m h&#xE1; acentos </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

It doens't seem JSDOM API has this option, but I'm having a hard time finding all text elements with jquery also.
Any suggestion?

Thanks,

---

PS: **Some of the things I tried:**

```
    function recursiveReplace(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("1", "۱");
    } else if (node.nodeType == 1) { // element
        $(node).contents().each(function () {
            recursiveReplace(this);
        });
    }
}

recursiveReplace(document.body);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494259/jquery-change-all-elements-text)

And

```
$('body').text()
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533860/jquery-get-the-text-of-all-elements-in-a-page), which replaces all the body with just the text, instead of the text inside the tags.

And some other...